# What is the fastest way to get a shallow copy the data of an object?

Tags: javascript

**Vanilla JS only please**

That is, its the output should be an object that only contains data, and ignores the original's methods/prototype.  Complex data structures that inherit from the default `Object`, like `Array`, can be copied in a shallow manner, as references.  The way I do it now is:

```
function shallowCopyObjectData(obj) {
  output = {};
  for (var i in item) {
    output[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return output;
};
```

The other way I've seen is:

```
function shallowCopyObjectData(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
};
```

What is the most performant way to do it?

**I've made a running jsPerf to compare speeds.  If you come up with a solution, please feel free to fork and add: http://jsperf.com/shallow-object-data-copy**

**Edit**
@Barmar: I know a [similar question has already been posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object), but it asked about the fastest way to clone an object, which implied a deep copy that keep the constructor, prototype, etc.  This question asks about the fastest way to copy just the data in the top level

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think its fair to mark this as a duplicate.  The other question asked about the fastest way to clone an object, which implied a deep copy that keep the constructor, prototype, etc.  This question asks about the fastest way to copy just the data in the top level.  I feel like those are two different things...

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is much, much, faster than traversing each node of an object.

Comment: Really?  Even if I have non-compliant data-types (like functions) as object properties?

Comment: Anecdotal example: I have a webapp that traverses and caches data on 53,000 objects. It was giving my node app a huge delay hit when it ran, taking up to 75829ms to finish loading everything. I swapped it with a parse/stringify, and it sped up to 718ms.

Comment: Do you actually *need* to shallow-copy the entire object? Or is there some predictable set of property names you can use?

Comment: I want to add, that functions don't seem to properly get saved with parse/stringify. :|

Comment: @meagar: yes, the property list is completely unpredictable.

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper: hmmmm, just added a jsPerf I made for my two versions, and the for loop seems a bit faster.  It doesn't try to mess with and ignore functions in that example though.

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper They definitely don't. JSON is not JavaScript, it doesn't have functions. You cannot JSON-encode functions.

Comment: Perhaps `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is only faster on an array of objects, not one.

Comment: If your objects are known to have the same structure (tabular data) you could generate a cloner. And gain a huge performance boost since your objects will share the same hidden class. http://jsperf.com/shallow-object-data-copy/3

Comment: Wow, that is a huge boost.  Unfortunately the contents and structure of the object are completely arbitrary.

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper DO NOT use `JSON.stringify`, what if the object has a method?

Comment: Performance is always a combination of many factors. Optimize data structure may bring you much benefit as well. Don't just look at one point (and sometimes, unfortunately, might not be the real bottle neck).

Comment: @Leo yea we discussed that earlier. For my particular case, my objects did not contain functions, so `JSON.stringify` met my needs and was much more performant than parsing through 53,000 objects.

Comment: These don't even do the same thing!  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` will do a _deep_ copy, not a shallow one.

Comment: I tried this with ES6 object spread, and wow! I cannot believe object spread is **this** slow. https://jsperf.com/es6-shallow-copy-object

Comment: To be entirely fair, it seems like Object.assign (and ES6 spread, which I believe is just syntactic sugar on Object.assign) does a little more under the hood than the for loop, so its not entirely surprising that it runs a bit slower: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

Comment: You're using **shallow copy** in a very non-standard way. What you want is not called **shallow copy**. I'm not sure what you want has a name but what I'm certain is that it's not shallow copy. Shallow copy is copying pointers/references instead of values

Answer (score 5):

The [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object. 
Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, };
var new_obj = Object.assign({}, obj);
console.log(new_obj); //{ a: 1, b: 2, }
console.log(new_obj == obj); //false
```

Comment: Hi - can you please add a little bit more context/an explanation for your answer please? :)

Comment: eslint recommends using the spread operator `var new_obj = {...obj}` it's available in all modern web browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use spread just like;

```js
var o = {a:1,b:2,c:3},
    r = {...o}; // shallow clone

r.a = 11;       // r's "a" property is set to 11
console.log(r); // check
console.log(o); // r is not a reference to a
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Object.assign` to fast clone object. The syntax is `Object. assign(originObject, extendObject)`. It will return the object that have property of originObject and extendObject.

For example I have the code here:

```js
var originObject = {value: 1};
var extendObject = {key: 2};
var shadowObject = {};

// Now I want clone originObject to shadow object
shadowObject = Object. assign(originObject, {});
// shadowObject = {value: 1}

// If you want clone originObject and extendObject to one object
shadowObject = Object. assign(originObject, shadowObject);
// shadowObject = {value: 1, key: 2}
```

Answer (score -2):

Note that if you know the property names in advance, you can get multiple orders of magnitude of improvement by writing them out in an object literal:

```
function cloneObject(obj) = {
    return {
        "property1": obj.property1,
        "property2": obj.property2,
        //Etc.
    }
}
```

Anything that involves a loop is going to be slow, so if there's an easy way to avoid the loop, do that instead.

Here are the results of some tests I ran in the most recent (as of April
2023) version of Chrome:

- `structuredClone(obj)`: 200 copies per ms.
- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`: 400 copies per ms.
- Getting the object's properties with `Object.keys()` and looping over them with a `while` loop, removing the first element from the list on each iteration: 2000 copies per ms.
- Getting the object's properties with `Object.keys` and looping over them with `forEach()`: 2100 copies per ms.
- Getting the object's properties with `Object.keys()` and looping over them with a traditional for loop: 2250 copies per ms.
- Looping over a predefined list of properties with `for... of`: 2300 copies per ms.
- `{...obj}`: 2500 copies per ms.
- `Object.assign({}, obj)`: 3100 copies per ms.
- Object literal with predefined properties: 1 **million** copies per ms.

Comment: Please add the actual tests you ran. The times depend on the number of properties on the object.

Comment: They were all run with the same object properties. (13 in this case.) I'm not claiming that other people will get the exact same times, it's just to illustrate the point that some things are much faster than others.

Comment: I cannot reproduce these timings. I did a test that compares object spread with the `Object.keys().forEach` solution, and the latter is 10 times slower. Please prove your claims with a script that can reproduce those timings (approximately).

Comment: You're right, I completely misunderstood how forEach() works, and was also looking at the wrong field in the Chrome profiler so was seeing incorrect results. Oops. I've edited my answer to hopefully be correct now; thank you for catching that.

Answer (score -5):

I think your asking about Deep Cloning (Copy). A shallow copy is as simple as assigning the original object to the new variable.

```
var originalObj = { someKey: 1 };
var copyObj = originalObj;
```

Comment: I think there is a big difference. Assigning reference doesn't create a new object, shallow copy does. In the example you gave, `copyObj === originalObj` will give `true`, but it should be `false` for shallow copy.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. You're mixing identity and value. You can assign a value to a new identity (variable name) without copying the underlying value. OP asks about shallow copying. This can only happen on the actual value by definition of the operation. `Object.assign` or JS spread operator aka `{...obj}` are the way to go.